# 'document' within a child window unexpectedly refers to parent

Tags: javascript, dom, parent, document

I opened a child window, then wrote HTML and so on to it using

```
childhandle.document.write(...)
```

That worked fine. 
The HTML included an input with ID 'foo'.
Then I tried

```
childhandle.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) { (document.getElementById('foo').value = 'bar'; });
```

This gave a TypeError. It works if I change it to

```
childhandle.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) { (childhandle.document.getElementById('foo').value = 'bar'; });
```

It seems that with version one the code must have been looking for element 'foo' in the parent document. That seems odd - surely the EventListener function is running in the scope of the child?
Can someone explain what's happening here? Thanks.

Comment: Come to think of it, how come childhandle is even defined when the function runs?

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous callback function is defined in the parent window, where `childhandle` is defined and where `document` refers to the parent window document, where it is executed wouldn't matter.
Try using `this` to refer to the current document.

```
childhandle.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
    function(event) { 
        this.getElementById('foo').value = 'bar'; 
    }
);
```